# Is there really no click event for all ExtJS components

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm learning extjs 4.1 and I can't find click event on most of the components - I'm I blind or I'm unable to react on click on other components than button?

What is the reason? HTML supports click on all elements.

Comment: Components that need click events have such event such as [buttons](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-event-click). Which components exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Panel, combobox... every single component with graphical representation needs click event

Comment: The click on panel and combobox is handled internally by ExtJS, as ExtJS defines various behaviours to what happens when the user clicks on a panel (its header, tool button, etc.) or on a combo box or its trigger. Are you confusing this with the dom element for which there is also a click event?

Comment: I'm not confusing anything - why can't I put my own handle to event that is ALSO handled by ExtJS?

Comment: That's because an ExtJS component does not resolve into a single dom element. In fact, it can be made of tens of these. So a click on a panel is not exactly defined - a click where? On the content? On the title bar? On the toolbar? Footer? The drag handler in a resizable layout? ExtJS component needs to response to various click event to achieve their task. You can always hook on the dom element event click, as in the answer you have accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every component can have the click event exposed at the element level.  Some components like `Ext.button.Button` have a click event at the component level.

Here is a nice way to add a click event on a panel:

```
  new Ext.panel.Panel({
      listeners: {
          click: this.handlePanelClick,
          element: 'el'
      }
  });
```

edit to respond to comment

The element string is a any element that is a property of the component.

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
listeners: {
    click: function() {
        alert('you clicked the body');
    },
    element: 'body'
}
```

});

The Ext docs have a more thorough explanation http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener

Comment: what are the other options for element parameter in this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can add any DOM event pretty easily by accessing the [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) object that almost all visible components contain once it has been rendered.

Simply add a listener to the `afterrender` event that adds the event you want to the dom object.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    // other panel configs ...
    listeners: {
       'afterrender': function(panel) {
           panel.el.on('click', function() {
               alert('clicked');
           });
        }
    }
});
```

I think there is also a way to do it for all components of a class that extends [Ext.util.Observable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable) (all visible components). I haven't done it before so you would have to play around with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a self-referencing managed listener (cleanest imo):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    listeners: {
       'afterrender': function(panel) {
           this.mon(this.getEl(), 'click', this.onClick, this)
        }
    },
    onClick: function() {
        alert("mmm mon mon mon");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am curious why you think this is the cleanest.  Also this seems like a misuse of `mon`.  `mon` is used to remove a listener when the item is destroyed, since the element will be destroyed when the component is destroyed it doesn't do anything extra here.

Comment: you are thinking of `mun` (shorthand for remove managed listener)

Comment: Umm no, from the docs : mon Shorthand for addManagedListener `Adds listeners to any Observable object (or Ext.Element) which are automatically removed when this Component is destroyed.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only listening to click event you can also do this

```
    xtype: 'container',
    listeners: {
         el: {
             click: function() {
                  alert('I clicked');
              },
              scope: this
             }
     }
```

If you need to listen to an event that the Ext.dom.Element does not fire, you will need to attach it in the 'render' listener, like others have suggested.